# SQLBulkCopy Throws InvalidOperationException Nullable Ints

Tags: c#, sql, nullable, sqlbulkcopy, invalidoperationexception

I have a DataTable that I am attempting to upload, but I run into the following exception:
"The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column."

The only reason I can think that it could possibly be doing this is that there are empty cells in the DataTable being uploaded to a column of type INT.  I try switching all empty values for DBNull.Value, but that doesn't seem to work for this specific column.  The upload process is as follows:

```
private void UploadTable(string tableName, DataTable table)
    {
        foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns)
                if (r[c].ToString().Trim() == "")
                    r[c] = DBNull.Value;
        }

        using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon))
        {

            copy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            try
            {
                copy.WriteToServer(table);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Content = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

The schema that I upload to is:

```
[dbo].[table](
[Date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[Dollar] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[tick] [varchar](10) NULL,
[id1] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Total Quantity] [int] NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NULL
)
```

Is there something special regarding SQLBulkCopy and nullable int coolumns that I don't know about?  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Where is it throwing the error? At the `copy.WriteToServer(table);
` line?

Comment: @Abe Miessler - More then likely - yes - it could be because the default type is string, he needs to specify int.

Comment: try changing r[c] = DBNull.Value to r[c] = null

Comment: @paolo - it throws the same error

Comment: @paolo - DBNull.Value is the correct way.

Comment: @JonH you're right, my mystake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad file input caused errors- had decimals in it and was not supposed to

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify the column type to be `int` when you add datacolumns to the datatable?

Comment: I did not, I will try to do that manually.  I would have another issue with this, however, because the method I use now adds the columns dynamically using: http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/ and I'm not sure how to get the datatype of that column.

Comment: @SeanVDH - I've never used that library but there has to be a property that displays the type of column.  Within excel you can get the format of a column by right clicking it..so there must be some sort of equivalent.  In any event, your error is due to the fact that the column is a string rather then what you want a number, namely an int.

Comment: I'm not positive if what you said is true, because I've never run into this error before and I'm reasonably certain I've tried this- I think that DBNull.Value should work regardless.  In any case, you pointed me towards the error- the datafile was bad, and had a decimal in it. I'm a bit new to the forum- do I still  mark your answer as correct/mark it up?

Comment: @SeanVDH I think you should post the right answer yourself and mark it as the right answer (so the future readers of your quetion will know what the answer was). However you're very welcome to vote JonH's answer up, since he pointed you to the solution. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @SeanVDH - Doesn't matter to me, I'm here to help I don't really care about the points I can't trade them in :0).  I'm just glad you got your issue resolved and I was able to point you a little :o).

Comment: @JonH you can't trade them in?? Then I'm outta here! Joking aside: I wasn't suggesting to upvote you to boost your reputation (which by the way is not bad at all, sure you don't wanna trade?). It's just that your answer, although not the problem in SeanDVH's particular case, is certainly something others might want to check if they have the same issue.